# foreign-key relationship with Doctrine concrete inheritance

Tags: inheritance, symfony1, doctrine, foreign-key-relationship

In my schema, I have a generic table `Animal` and an inherited table `Dog`.
Before using doctrine, I used to implement this pattern with an inherited id referencing the generic id as foreign key.
I can't reproduce the same with Doctrine, and I feel like something is missing.

The schema I used to produce is the following :

```
CREATE TABLE `animal` (
  `id` INT UNSIGNED NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `color` VARCHAR(20) NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
);

CREATE TABLE `dog` (
  `id` INT UNSIGNED NOT NULL,
  `breed` VARCHAR(40) NOT NULL,
  KEY `id` (`id`)
);

ALTER TABLE `dog` ADD CONSTRAINT FOREIGN KEY (`id`) REFERENCES `animal`(`id`);
```

I first tried to use Doctrine concrete inheritance, as it seemed the logical answer to this problem :

Here is the YAML file :

```
Animal:
  columns:
    id: { primary: true , type: integer ,  autoincrement: true }
    color: { type: string(20) , notnull: true }
Dog:
  columns:
    breed: { type: string(20) , notnull: true }
  inheritance:
    extends: Animal
    type: concrete
```

And the resulting SQL is :

```
CREATE TABLE `animal` (
  `id` BIGINT NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `color` VARCHAR(20) NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
);

CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `dog` (
  `id` BIGINT NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `color` VARCHAR(20) NOT NULL,
  `breed` VARCHAR(20) NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
);
```

The duplication of the `color` column is OK, but where is the foreign key ? How do I ensure the integrity of my `dog.id` with my `animal.id` ? And what happens if I delete `animal`'s rows ?

So I tried to use a simple one-to-one association :

```
Animal:
  columns:
    id: { primary: true , type: integer(10) , autoincrement: true }
    color: { type: string(20) , notnull: true }
Dog:
  columns:
    animal_id: { primary: true , type: integer(10) }
    breed: { type: string(20) , notnull: true }
  relations:
    AnimalRecord:
      class: Animal
      foreignAlias: DogRecord
      type: one
      foreignType: one
      local: animal_id
      foreign: id
```

The result is the same as above (except the `color` column isn't duplicated, which is normal since the inheritance isn't explicited anymore), still no foreign key.

If I just change the `animal_id` from `PRIMARY` to `UNIQUE`, the foreign key is created from `dog.animal_id` to `animal.id`, but a new autoincrement'ed `id` appears.

It all behaves like being `PRIMARY` or `FOREIGN KEY` are exclusive for a column, and I can't understand why. Furthermore, it seems to me like a dangerous flaw.

Comment: Why do you want to add a constraint on primary key?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you may want to re-read the documentation on concrete inheritance : the animal table will always be empty, because all the data you will give about the dog "medor" will be stored in the dog table when you use this inheritance strategy type. That's why there is no point to create a relation between animal and dog classes.

Animal is like an abstract class if you will.

To me, your schema should look like this:

```
Animal:
  columns:
    id: { primary: true , type: integer(10) , autoincrement: true }
    color: { type: string(20) , notnull: true }
Dog:
  columns:
    breed: { type: string(20) , notnull: true }
```

Comment: Sorry about this, I guess the documentation lacks some informations... http://www.doctrine-project.org/projects/orm/1.2/docs/manual/inheritance/fr#concrete Then is the autoincrement shared between inherited tables or just independant ? What is the point of this strategy of inheritance ?

Comment: @user750633: doctrine documentation does lack some informations, that's why you may want to read [this symfony page about inheritance](http://www.symfony-project.org/more-with-symfony/1_4/en/09-Doctrine-Form-Inheritance)

Comment: Thanks for the link... I think i really took it the wrong way, as I wanted to use inheritance to share one only autoincrement between ids. Still, I think my main problem remains. Even without inheritance, is it possible in Doctrine to define a primary key to be a foreign key as well ? If not, is there a theoratical explanation ?

Comment: @user750633: Good questions, I have no clue. Maybe this feature is not supported by all RDBMS? But I think you should migrate your schema to something compatible with one of Doctrine's representation of inheritance, so that you can take advantage of inheritance in your code after this. Not easy though. Good luck and +1 for your question.